# Setting document style width with Javascript makes the animation go from left to right. How do I counteract this?

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a (currently empty) div with just the id "menu".
I gave it some CSS:

```
#menu {
    height:70%;
    width:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    transition:0.2s;
    padding-top:70px;
}
```

inspired almost entirely by W3S' sidebar. I also have another div with onclick="openMenu()" and the function itself is

```
document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "250px";
```

So the issue is that despite working, the (currently blank) menu opens from left to right and not right to left or even middle to ends. Is this some default behaviour or an issue in my code? And to fix it, do I need to use CSS before and after or...

edit: I realise transition:0.2s is probably the culprit but I would still like to leave it in there

edit2: I should clarify that my goal is to have a sidebar open in the middle of the screen upon clicking a div. Therefore it should be invisible on startup and then open up (by adding width) with a click, hence the JS. My issue of course is that I would prefer the menu to transition from nothing into something by opening up both ways (instead of left to right) from the middle of the screen or simply making it reverse-fade into existence

Comment: Currently your transition property is applying a 0.2s animation to every property - generally you should have this only set the relevant properties. Aside from that, the width of an element expands from left to right due to how elements are rendered. Increasing the width will increase it to the right. So when you set the width, it's updating over 0.2s (due to transition) and seemingly moving from left to right.

Comment: Instead of increasing the width, you could either start with a negative offset and then set it back to the desired value, or simply hide the menu `display:none;` and then show via JS depending on what you want to do

Comment: thanks for the descriptive answers, but how would I go about starting with a negative offset?

Comment: If you want it to "slide in" from the left - start with something like `left: -50%`, then when you want to show it, change it to `left: 50%`. If you do this, make sure you first give your menu some width otherwise it probably won't be visible.

Comment: please read my second edit to clarify my goals

Comment: Thanks for the edit, makes it much clearer. When the menu is opening up 'from the middle' do you want the text in it to appear that way? e.g. if 'About us' is one of the items then (roughly) the t and space appear first then 'ut u' and so on?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet shows a very simple approach that you can take for what you're after

Instead of using JS to control the individual CSS properties, it's often better to use classes which you can toggle via JS

```js
document.getElementById("toggle-menu").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#menu {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  background:#f57777;
  border-radius:4px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  margin:auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #aaa;
}

#menu.active {
  display:block;
}

#toggle-menu {
  background: #fafafa;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  border-radius:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle-menu">Toggle Menu</div>
<div id="menu">
Your content in here
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton, that's great. How would I go about animating that though? A simple fade-in would work

Answer (score 0):

If you position the menu in the center as required and cover it with two 'curtains', one on the left and one on the right, you can shrink them both down to 0 width to reveal the menu from the center outwards.

This snippet does this by introducing before and after pseudo elements which have the same background color as the surroundings (white in this instance) with width 50% of the menu width and before anchored on the left and after on the right.

```css
#menu {
  height: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu::before,
#menu::after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: width .2s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu::before {
  left: 0;
}

#menu::after {
  right: 0;
}

#menu.expand::before,
#menu.expand::after {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#menu').classList.toggle('expand')">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="menu">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is very smart, thanks for making this! Is there any way to get them to be the background color of what they're on though? I have different background colors on my page unfortunately

Comment: Does that background color differ from the background color of the menu? And how is the background color of the page set? I would do it by giving a CSS variable the page background color and using that - is that possible?

Comment: You could use JS to find the computed background color of the body or header or whatever element the menu is sitting on top of. Can't tell without seeing your HTML structure.